# Access the return value from the chrome.cookies.get function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to access the variable "radium"" outside this function.

`chrome.cookies.get({"url": "https://www.test.com/", "name": "radium"}, function(cookie) { radium = cookie.value; console.log(radium);//returns the value });`

`console.log(radium)//returns undefined`

Having the same issue with this question in stackoverflow:
[Chrome extensions - Turning chrome.cookies.get into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572074/chrome-extensions-turning-chrome-cookies-get-into-a-variable)

I did try to declare radium variable as a global variable above chrome.cookies.get() but no luck

Comment: Either use the variable inside the callback or switch to the `async/await` syntax.